# android - Map coordinates to imageview

Tags: android

I've used this to map my coordinates that I marked on my Imageview to be the coordinates on the bitmap itself.

```
final float[] getPointerCoords(ImageView view, MotionEvent e)
{
    final int index = e.getActionIndex();
    final float[] coords = new float[] { e.getX(index), e.getY(index) };
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    view.getImageMatrix().invert(matrix);
    matrix.postTranslate(view.getScrollX(), view.getScrollY());
    matrix.mapPoints(coords);
    return coords;
}
```

I need to write a function that will receive coordinates and map them to the Imageview in order to mark some points on it (after some calculations I made).

Can you help me please?

Comment: Could you please describe your problem / error? You are basically describing what the code you are showing is doing

Comment: After mapping the points marked on the imageview, I did some calculations on them. Now, I have some new points I want to mark on the imageview that are results of those calculations. I want to mark them on the imageview, but I want the mark to relative to the imageview. Basically I want to reset the mapping this function did to my new points.